# Solving an Absolute Value Inequality Clarification

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, convergence-divergence

I have the following inequality that I need to solve:

$|\frac{3}{x^2}| < 1$

**My approach**:

$-1 < \frac{3}{x^2} < 1$

I separated it into two inequalities: $\frac{3}{x^2} > -1$ and $\frac{3}{x^2} < 1$

- Solving for the $\frac{3}{x^2} < 1$, for which I got $a < \sqrt{3}$.
- Solving for the $\frac{3}{x^2} > -1$ is where the trouble starts for me. I multiplied both sides by $x^2$ and got $3 > -x^2$. I then proceeded to take the square root of both sides $\sqrt{3} > -x$. Now dividing by $-1$ I changed the symbol to its opposite, as per the rule: $\sqrt{3} < x$.  I know that this is not the correct answer, so where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac 3 {x^2}\,$ is always positive so you can rewrite it as follows:
$$\frac 3 {x^2} \lt 1$$
that is equivalent to
$$\frac {x^2} 3 \gt 1$$
$$x^2 \gt 3$$
that is satisfied by
$$x \gt \sqrt 3 $$
$$x \lt -\sqrt 3 $$